# Is -g the same as -g2 for gcc and clang?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, clang

[GCC debug option documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) is not that comprehensive. So trying to compile a binary with different options `-g`, `-g1`, `-g2`, `-g3` I got the following result.

When compiling with `-g` and `-g2` binary has the same `13KB` in size.

When compiling with `-g1` the binary ended up in `9.3KB` in size

When compiling with `-g3` the binary has `73KB` in size

So is `-g` equivalent to `-g2`? But the level 2 is not even explained in the documentation. Here is what the docs say (no level 2):

> Level 0 produces no debug information at all. Thus, -g0 negates -g.
>
> Level 1 produces minimal information, enough for making backtraces in
> parts of the program that you don’t plan to debug. This includes
> descriptions of functions and external variables, and line number
> tables, but no information about local variables.
>
> Level 3 includes extra information, such as all the macro definitions
> present in the program. Some debuggers support macro expansion when
> you use -g3.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I personally only use -g3. -g2 includes everything except macros.

Comment: The gcc man page says: "The default level is 2", so `-g` and `-g2` are the same, but it doesn't explain what `-g2` does either. Seems like a huge oversight that the default is unexplained.

Comment: @sj95126, the default is not unexplained.  Rather, it is explained earlier, for the "`-g`" spelling of the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is `-g` equivalent to `-g2`?

Yes.

> But the level 2 is not even explained in the documentation. [...] Or am I missing something?

You are missing something.  You have overlooked the sentence immediately preceding your quotation:

> The default level is 2.

This means that `-g2` means the same thing as `-g`.  (And `-ggdb2` means the same thing as `-ggdb`, *etc*.)  This serves in part as a reference for each of the `-g*2` options to the docs of the corresponding unnumbered `-g*` options, where you will find the relevant documentation.  In particular, the documentation for `-g2` is the documentation for `-g`, which appears first in the section.

Comment: And what is explained there? Basically nothing. What is gdb-specific information? Do you know from there? This answer does not explain anything.

Comment: @0___________, the question is not what each debug level does, it is whether `-g2` is the same as `-g`, and a bit of a slide into "and where are the docs for `-g2`?"  This answer answers the question posed.  As for what the docs do say, it is that debug information is emitted in the default (or specified) format.  That's not "nothing", it's *everything* (by reference).